# How to check what process is writing to hard drive in shell

Tags: linux, shell

Currently the free space of my hard disk is shrinking for unknown reason. The free space keeps reducing until no space lefts. I don't know what's the cause, so I want to inspect to see what process is the culprit and terminate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iotop` is to the hard disk what as `top` is to the CPU.

Among other things, it displays how many bytes per second all available proccesses are writing to the disk.

On Ubuntu, you can install it with `apt-get install iotop`.

Answer (score 3):

`lsof +d / | awk '$4 ~ /.*[uw]/'` will list all processes with files open for reading or updating.